# Xcode crashing when fetching team list

Tags: xcode, crash, itunes

So basically Xcode 6.1 is crashing whenever it's trying to get team list. From the general tab in the main screen, when trying to submit the app to iTunes, trying to validate the app.. whenever it tries to get team list, it crashes. It is working fine an hour ago but when we added some team members in the iTunes account for internal testing, it started crashing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Currently this just started happening for me as well, and so far I have traced it back to Crashlytics. If you have Crashlytics installed, I believe that is currently the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have submitted a Bug Report to Apple. When they get back to me I'll let you know.

Comment: This is happening to me and to other developers with unrelated projects. Seems to be a server-side issue.

Comment: I also just started having this issue last night.  From the crash report it looks like they are calling "longLongValue" on NSNull which is a typical "JSON" parsing error.   I would agree this looks like a server side issue.  I tried disabling my internet to keep it from refreshing but still no luck

Comment: Same here - hopefully Apple fixes this quickly!

Comment: I found a solution. You can see my answer below :) Hope it helps!

Comment: It started working out of nowhere. Probably the server-side issue was fixed. :)

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here, however it's possible to compile and generate a .ipa file by the command line interface:

```
xcodebuild archive -project $projectname.xcodeproj -scheme $schemename -archivePath projectname.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks.  I got this to work by running from "%>cd /Users/<name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<date>/" and putting single quotes around the profile name.  Mine was like '<company> AdHoc Distribution'

Comment: Works even if your Developer Program Membership is expired.

Answer (score 3):

I was crashing too (while fetching teams) and I finally got it fixed...

1. Open Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts
2. Check that each of the accounts is valid. I had two there that were expired/old developer accounts, no longer in use. I removed both of them and now the crash is gone for me.

Hope this works for you :O

Answer (score 1):

We find a solution.

You could use Shenzhen. This is a command line util developed by Mattt Thompson.

Install:

```
$ gem install shenzhen
```

If you see permission errors, you can execute the command with sudo

After install, go to project folder and:

```
$ ipa build
```

Before, you need to configure your build settings on the XCode Project like usual.

More info and examples here: https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen

These save my day, I hope the same for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading with Application Loader

`Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader`

Enter the iTunes Connect details.

Comment: Can't get there either. It has to fetch team list before it will let me export the build for application loader. We tried.

Comment: Try `Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Apple ID's`. Delete the one you want, and just re add it again. Think this will refresh it?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If you think old accounts are to blame, try 'fixing' them by joining the Safari Developer Program (free).

Why I tried this:

I couldn't open the accounts tab or any dropdowns related to accounts. I had an old iOS Developer account, that had expired.

Ultimately I decided my old account was corrupt on Apple's side (somehow) and logged into their certificates page.

Not wanting to pay the $99 --to join the iOS program--, just to fix a crashing xcode I signed up for the free Safari Developer program.

Instantly my account in xcode stopped causing crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple "fixed" the problem by Sunday (11/16). I was experiencing it too, and none of the suggestions worked for me. On Sunday it was magically working again.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @cclogg's advice and saw that there was an expired account that was crashing. However, it wouldn't let me select the account without crashing XCode. I was only able to do this by selecting two accounts together and this prevented XCode from trying to fetch account information.

After that, I clicked on the minus button to delete both accounts. I figured it would be easier to re-add the second account. And now, the crashing problem is gone.