# Version 6.0 (6A313) crash when refreshing provisioning profiles

Tags: crash, refresh, xcode6, provisioning

Refreshing provisioning profile in Xcode 6 worked for me for a while and xcode 6  crashes today when I refresh it .

Any one can help?
I saw there is a ticket on stackoverflow and it does not help in my case.

"Xcode crash when refreshing provisioning profiles"

[Xcode crash when refreshing provisioning profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434296/xcode-crash-when-refreshing-provisioning-profiles)

Thanks in advance.

```
 Process:         Xcode [979]
```

Path:            /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0 (6299)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6299000000000000~8
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [357]
Responsible:     Xcode [979]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-11-14 11:14:00.919 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  13628E65-2AA7-5BA1-59E1-B82B3CC26059

Crashed Thread:  15  Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A313
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSNull longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff7c4ba240
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff93a58244 **exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010c119184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff963ffe75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff93a5b12d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff939b6272 ___forwarding_** (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff939b5df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x00007fff93eb952b -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] (in CoreData)
  7  0x00007fff93ed3fd0 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT (in CoreData)
  8  0x00007fff93ec085f -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] (in CoreData)
  9  0x00007fff93ec0397 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] (in CoreData)
 10  0x00007fff93ebfe63 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] (in

abort() called

This is part of crash log.

Comment: I am also in the same boat. It started last night. Seems on Yosemite there is no crash but never loads. This crash also happens when you archive and export.

Comment: Also happening to me on trying to export an ad hoc archive.

Comment: I was experiencing this a few days ago, but it appears to have resolved itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works later without any change. It may be caused by developer center issue.

Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this problem is temporary and nothing to do with your Xcode or developer account.... most probably with apple servers/APIs that deals with prov/dev account. I am also getting same crash for last couple of hours. I tried many things - clean derived data, cache. Restarted machine etc but all in vain.

---

**UPDATE: Try this on 'Terminal' app... [My issue probably resolved due to this !]**

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

---

Thanks for putting up this question here so I know there are others facing this problem. No useful info on google.

The crash log that I get when I click Xcode project > Target > Team pop up -

```
Process:         Xcode [5047]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.1 (6604)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6604000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 752282650
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [367]
Responsible:     Xcode [5047]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-11-14 15:17:59.448 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  7950E54F-D23B-CF06-2654-85C6536B1DB5


Crashed Thread:  13  Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSNull longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff7c399240
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff8ffad244 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000105c4e2f4 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff91ce1e75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff8ffb012d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8ff0b272 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff8ff0adf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x00007fff9119152b -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] (in CoreData)
  7  0x00007fff911abfd0 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT (in CoreData)
  8  0x00007fff9119885f -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] (in CoreData)
  9  0x00007fff91198397 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] (in CoreData)
 10  0x00007fff91197e63 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] (in CoreData)
 11  0x00007fff91195c1b -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] (in CoreData)
 12  0x0000000105b573e5 __80+[DVTDeveloperPortalDatabase objectsWithEntityName:matchingPredicate:inContext:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to know the answer to this as well. Getting same thing - only solution found so far is related to Xcode 4. I did discover that it is somehow related to derived data...

Answer (score 0):

Reference to this thread:
[Xcode crashing when fetching team list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920235/xcode-crashing-when-fetching-team-list)

In case you want to export an ipa:

```
xcodebuild archive -project $projectname.xcodeproj -scheme $schemename -archivePath projectname.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good solution but I was able to upgrade to Yosemite and it resolved these issues.