# Xcode crashes when exporting or submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm having problems submitting to the App Store.  Both Xcode 6.1 and 5.1.1 crash when I attempt to export an .ipa or use the submit feature after the app has been archived.  Here are the steps to reproduce:

Build -> Archive -> Organizer -> Export -> Save for iOS App Store Deployment

The "Fetching list of teams..." dialogue appears briefly and then Xcode crashes.  This also occurs when clicking the Submit button on the Organizer window.  This also occurs for Ad Hoc exports.  This is odd as I was able to create an ad hoc distribution a few days ago without issue.

I am also unable to select the Team attribute for the target in the project files general settings (General -> Identity -> Team).

The crash report for all of the issues above are similar.  I have double checked the developer center to ensure that I have an App Store provisioning profile for this app.  I have also read of people having a similar issue if they had not agreed to the latest developer center terms.  As far as I can tell, I don't have any outstanding agreements that require action.  I've tried removing my account from Xcode and reinstalling.  I'm guessing this is an account issue but I'm not sure what I can do to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965823/5523205

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by Apple.

[Apple Developer Forums Thread (developer account required)](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1073082#1073082)

Comment: They may have closed the issue...but that doesn't mean it is fixed.  The issue still exists as of 6.3

Comment: It has not been resolved. Still experiencing this issue as of 8/10.

Answer (score 24):

close the Xcode and keep the organizer is opened and try to submit; it's working with me

enjoy!

Comment: Closing the project window while keeping Organizer open also worked for me.  How dumb is this?  <Shakes fist> Xcode!

Comment: Close Xcode the window while keeping organizer window open

Answer (score 16):

It was crashing for me in `XCode 9.3` and the reason was I have not accepted the latest agreement at https://developer.apple.com/. Right after accepting the latest agreement it just worked.

Right after crashing OS will provide you with a pop-up with logs. Just go through the log and see whether you can make up what exactly happened. Sometimes this is how you can figure out the issue.

Comment: I had the same behavior, also with Xcode 9.3 (Version 9.3 (9E145)). On every crash i saw the following log entry in " /var/log/system.log": com.apple.dt.SKAgent[6470]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[mach_recv] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked

Comment: I had to accept a new agreement too, but additional, after that, I need to archive a new build and re-add the dev-account in xcode's prefs. Then it worked.

Comment: Still crashing in Xcode 9.4.1, when exporting a build at the step "communicating with Apple". After accepting the new developer agreement, it exported fine.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the Apple Membership is expired in my case. Check Membership Center if there is anything worth noticing.

Comment: That was my issue too. Sad that Xcode just crashes when this happens.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that there was a **new user agreement** waiting approval in my dev account so the solution was to login to my account here https://developer.apple.com/ and then agreeing to the user agreement they had.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem starting from yesterday, 11/13/2014.

Whenever tried to communicate with server it crashed

- Preferences -> Apple ID -> View Details
- Organizer -> Validate
- Organizer -> Export -> Save for Ad Hoc Deployment

View Details works today, but Validate and Export are still crashing.

[Edited]
Reference to this thread:
[Xcode crashing when fetching team list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920235/xcode-crashing-when-fetching-team-list)

In case you want to export an ipa:

```
xcodebuild archive -project $projectname.xcodeproj -scheme $schemename -archivePath projectname.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

Comment: The started for me on 11/13/2014 as well.  My last successful export (ad hoc for TestFlight) was on 11/11/2014.  It is still crashing when I refresh from View Details.

Answer (score 0):

Export an .ipa from Organizer and use the Application Loader to upload your app to iTunesConnect.

Comment: Read Question carefully.. Its about export issue itself. How will he upload IPA via App Loader

Answer (score -1):

If the data at the developer center looks good, open Xcode Prefs, click Accounts, click "View Details", click the refresh button. Then quit and relaunch Xcode for good measure, and see if uploading now works. This voodoo has always worked for me in the past.

[Addition]
In the release notes for Xcode 6.1.1 Apple suggests trying this if you crash during App Store submission:
App Store Submission
• Using the distribution workflow after deleting an account from Xcode's preferences may lead to a crash. (18964743)
Workaround: Delete all files ending with ".db" in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried refreshing from that context and it crashed.  The crash report is exactly what I have been seeing when attempting the export/submit.  Seems like theres a problem when Xcode tries to communicate with dev center.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting a crash in 6.3.2. Then I tried closing Xcode before submitting and realized that I was using the same build number as my rejected version of the app. I updated the build number and it submitted without having to close Xcode.

Answer (score -2):

close the Xcode and keep the organizer is opened and try to submit; it's working with me also

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?