# Xcode 9 crashes while exporting ipa from archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an archive for any project in Xcode 9. Then I try to create an ipa file (either development or ad-hoc). I first try to export the archive. Then I select either Development or AdHoc Distribution. The Xcode 9 crashes. I even added 'compile bitcode' option in the app's info.plist. I am able to create an ipa with the same project in Xcode 8.

Bug report :

```
Process:               Xcode [6854]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode9.0.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0 (13247)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13247000000000000~26
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [6854]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-11-07 16:13:32.644 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        E7160691-62F7-DE54-A767-EF456EC37FEC


Time Awake Since Boot: 10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        15  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010b094000-000000010b096000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode9.0.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9A235

....
```

Comment: Same problem...

Answer (score 8):

In my case this was due to a pending Apple license agreement that was causing Xcode's automatic provisioning to crash.

Log onto [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/) and make sure you do not have a license update pending agreement.

Comment: Omfg Apple... Each time I think they won't be able to top it, but they do...
Thank you for the tip.

Comment: We should make a conference at Apple in CA to sensibilise their dev to the use of try catch and error messages lol

Comment: Great catch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expired provision profile was the cause of this same issue. After renewal, everything is now working.

Answer (score 0):

The "Apple Developer Program License Agreement" has been updated.

So I have to accept pending License Agreement.

When I select Manual manage signing and try to download profile then I got following error

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try export with Manually first after that you can comeback with Automatically. I think this one fault when apple server return data for exporting process. It can be reset the process with manually option.