# Xcode 9.3 crashes on exporting build

Tags: xcode9.2, xcode9.3

Xcode v9.3 crashes when I try exporting the IPA from the archive, whereas IPA successfully exported from Xcode v9.2.

Comment: Some error log which mentions what failed?

Comment: did not get any log because of xcode closed.

Comment: In that case it's difficult for anyone to identify what's wrong unless there's a compatibility issue between the two versions you mentioned. Check the release notes of xcode

Comment: In my case, this is due to not accept the new policy on the developer account. After accept, it gets resolved.

Comment: I am facing same issue and given +1 to your question. If you have found any solution please paste it here.

Comment: @AnilKukadeja  In my case, this is due to not accept the new policy on the developer account. After accept, it gets resolved.  if this doesn't work and your xcode getting crashed then after some time you will get a log with the reason of crashing, you can see main reason. you can forward to me also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965823/5523205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, this is due to not accept the new policy on the developer account. After accept, it gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as NitinSingh comment - go to iTunes Connect and accept policy. Strange anyway fixed